# DDMS not showing the name of application

Tags: android

I am facing this problem intermittently, the DDMS in Android does not show the name of any application as shown in the image below

[image]

This becomes such a major problem given the number of log messages it becomes impossible to see the relevant messages without setting the filter for a particular application.

**My Question**

What changes are required in the DDMS settings so that it always show the name of application in messages?

Comment: you can filter by tag, just type in the box.

Comment: @VaibhavMishra Thanks, I will do, but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: agreed , it is just a workaround, you should probably update your plugin, this happens sometimes when you have two ddms' but happens very rarely in my case, and usually I selected device wrong or something similar. I recall resetting ADB  did the trick for me.

Comment: @VaibhavMishra Please enter your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can filter by tag,  it is just a workaround, you should probably update your plugin, this happens sometimes when you have two ddms' but happens very rarely in my case, and usually I selected device wrong or something similar. I recall resetting ADB did the trick for me

Answer (score 4):

In Android Manifest, set the application Debuggeable = True 
works after that

Comment: Does not work at times even after setting `android:debuggable="true"`.